# How do I implement Grid level validation in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to implement grid level validation in a WPF datagrid. All the examples I can find relate to row and cell level validation.

The rules will apply to a subset of rows per ID where the rows have From and To dates

1. Only 1 row may have To Date Null
2. The current row From Date must not be between any other From / To date pair for this ID
3. Where the To Date is not null then it  must not be between any other From / To date pair for this ID.

Having considered this issue for a few days, the solution will be along these lines:

```
        private void unitDataGridEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            CUnitMasterBase workingRow = (CUnitMasterBase)e.Row.Item;
            CSharedVariables.m_FromToIssuesFlag dateIssues = CSharedVariables.m_FromToIssuesFlag.NONE;

            IEnumerable<CDates> unitDates = new List<CDates>(this.ViewModel.Units
               .Where(i => i.p_Unit_ID == workingRow.p_Unit_ID)
               .Select(d => new CDates ( d.p_Valid_From, d.p_Valid_To )));

            if (unitDates.Count() <= 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            dateIssues = sharedFunctions.Verify_Dates(unitDates, workingRow.p_Valid_From, workingRow.p_Valid_To);

            if (dateIssues !=  CSharedVariables.m_FromToIssuesFlag.NONE)
            {
                unitDataGrid.CancelEdit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=netcore-3.1) in your view model?

Comment: INotifyDataError is great for rows, but I can't make it work for a subset of the full grid. That said RowEndEdit might just work.

Comment: A "subset of the full grid" includes several rows, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: So what is your current question/issue?

Comment: I have edited the original question so that it now contains the code I believe represents the solution. There is no longer an outstanding issue but I would welcome alternative answers if there are any. Perhaps I should have posted that code as the answer rather than editing it into the question.

Comment: Yes, you probably should have.